# Анимация вытеснения изображений

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать анимацию, такую же как тут  ru.4game.com/lineage2classic/install/

Суть - при нажатии на кнопку одна картинка смещается вниз - другая наверх
при этом их должны выместить другие картинки, которые придут на смену предыдущим
У меня имеются 10 изображений (5 разрезанные на двое)
Пытался сделать таким образом

```
var animDown = new ThicknessAnimation();
        animDown.From = new Thickness(673, -688, -5, 0);
        animDown.To = new Thickness(673, 0, -4, 0);
        animDown.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        im2_2.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDown);
```

Но этот код перемещает только одну картинку...

Прошу помочь

---

```
private void AnimUp(Image img)
    {
        im4_4.Margin = new Thickness(673, 686, -5, -686);

        var animUp = new ThicknessAnimation();
        var animUp1 = new ThicknessAnimation();
        if (img.Margin == new Thickness(673, 0, -4, 0))
        {
            animUp.To = new Thickness(673, -688, -4, 0);
            animUp1.To = new Thickness(673, 0, -4, 0);
        }
        animUp.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        animUp1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        img.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animUp);

        im4_4.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animUp1);
        im4_4.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animUp1);

    }
    private void AnimDw(Image img)
    {
        im4.Margin = new Thickness(0, -687, 0, 0);
        var animDw = new ThicknessAnimation();
        var animDw1 = new ThicknessAnimation();
        if (img.Margin == new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            animDw.To = new Thickness(0, 687, 0, -687);
            animDw1.To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        animDw.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        animDw1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        img.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDw);
        im4.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDw1);
    }
    private void btnSlide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnimDw(im5);
        AnimUp(im5_5);
    }
```

Вот эта штука работает но так:  одни картинка смещает другую и обратно

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно за выполнение анимации для конкретного изображения отвечает следующая строка

```
im2_2.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDown);
```

У Вас в коде она, судя по всему одна. Так что нет ничего удивительного в том, что и перемещается только одно изображение. Для которого "назначена" эта анимация.

Для того чтобы решить данную задачу необходимо реализовать анимацию и для остальных изображений.

При этом код анимации можно вынести в отдельный метод. Например:

```
private void Anim (Image img, int delta)
        {
            var animDown = new ThicknessAnimation();
            animDown.From = new Thickness(27, img.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
            if (delta > 0)
            {
                animDown.To = new Thickness(27, img.Margin.Top + 10, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                animDown.To = new Thickness(27, img.Margin.Top - 10, 0, 0);
            }
            animDown.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            img.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDown);
        }
```

При вызове этого метода в обработчике события MouseWheel для двух изображений они будут синхронно перемещаться вверх или вниз, в зависимости от направления вращения колёсика мыши.

```
private void Grid_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {                
            Anim(image1, e.Delta);
            Anim(image2, e.Delta);
        }
```

Примерно как-то так. Надеюсь, что принцип ясен...

Comment: Это понятно, так вот как сделать чтобы вверх по очередному нажатию кнопки перемещались одни картинки, а другие вниз?

Comment: Для этого нужно реализовать анимацию и для остальных изображений. От того что она есть только у одного из них другие никуда двигаться не будут. Принцип реализации я подробно пояснил в ответе.

Comment: как я понимаю нужно сравнение - если позиция такая то - то сменить на другую позицию...   Но я не понимаю как мне добавить чтобы при очередном нажатии менялись изображения?

Comment: Зачем? Расположите несколько изображений друг под другом и при прокрутке они будут сменять друг друга как в Вашем примере по ссылке.

Comment: Немного не то (  одни картинка должна как бы сместить другую сверху вниз.. не понимаю я что то ((

Comment: Значит что-то не так делаете. Показывайте, что и как делаете (выложите код C# и XAML).

Comment: Код к сожалению большой( , он делает все верно но только для двух картинок(которые сверху..одна вниз другая вверх идут)   - после нажатия на кнопку еще раз - картинки опять приобретают начальный маргин и снова расползаются...а должно быть так чтобы они остались без изменений там, куда уехали, при этом  чтобы пока изменялся их маргин - изменялся маргин других картинок что снизу..  Если Вам удобно, мы можем поговорить в скайпе

Comment: Ну так сделайте минимальный пример, как это рекомендовано в справке. А, вообще проблема описанная в Вашем последнем комментарии, ИМХО, тянет на отдельный самостоятельный вопрос. В любом случае помощь только на сайте. А, помощь с кодом, включая вопросы отладки, только если есть Ваш код. Нет кода, соответственно... Не обижайтесь.

Comment: Код отправил как твет

Comment: Прочитал код. Откровенно говоря, сложилось впечатление, что Вы просто невнимательно прочитали мой ответ. Посмотрите ещё раз, но уже внимательно. Как передаётся изображение в метод реализующий анимацию, как выполняется его позиционирование и как выполнен вызов метода в обработчике.